Is there a Japanese expression equivalent to "To each his own"?
How to express a popular English idiom "To each his own"?
A quick search yields それぞれの好み, but I am not sure if it is widely used.

最新日米口語辞典 (a very old edition) lists that expression as a translation for 好きずき and gives the following example.

「彼女がなぜあんなヘアスタイルをしているのか私には理解できない」
「いつも言っているように、それは好きずきというもんですよ」


I can't understand why she wears her hair like that.
To each his own, I always say.

The dictionary also has this example with [蓼]{たで}食う虫も好きずき.

キャロルはデイブのバカのどこがいいんだろう、さっぱりわからんよ。まぁ、蓼食う虫も好きずきってやつだろうな。


What Carol sees in that jerk Dave, I'll never know. But I guess, as they say, to each his own.

蓼 is a plant with a strong taste and is used as a garnish for sashimi. It might not be very popular among insects. This expression 蓼食う虫も好きずき tends to be used for someone's peculiar taste for romantic partners as in the example above.
You can also use 人それぞれ if you want to simply say everyone has different preferences with no negative connotations.
